# How to get given users "Desktop Path"

Tags: linux, fedora

How can i get the path to the given users desktop?

I used this:

```
echo $(awk "NR==$(awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $3}' /etc/passwd | awk "/^$(id -u USERSNAMEHERE)$/ {print NR}")" /etc/passwd | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print $6}')/Desktop
```

are there any better ones?

What if the users Desktop's name isn't "Desktop"?

Thank you!

p.s.: using Fedora 14 but are there any "general" methods to find out the given users desktop?

Answer (score 6):

Try [xdg-user-dirs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs).

That page has an example that should work for the current user:

```
test -f ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/user-dirs.dirs && \
    source ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/user-dirs.dirs
echo ${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$HOME/Desktop}
```

Also, if you have to read `/etc/passwd`, it's better to use the output of `getent passwd`, because some user data might be stored in NIS, LDAP, or some other database.

Combining that so it works for a user called `USERSNAMEHERE`:

```
USER=USERSNAMEHERE
USERDIR=$(getent passwd $USER | cut -f 6 -d :)
USERDIRCONF=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$USERDIR/.config}/user-dirs.dirs
test -f "$USERDIRCONF" && . "$USERDIRCONF"
echo "${XDG_DESKTOP_DIR:-$USERDIR/Desktop}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command is impossibly complex.

Here is a simplified version:

```
getent passwd USERNAME | awk -F: '{print $6 "/Desktop"}'
```

Here is an untangled version of your original:

```
awk -v "id=$(id -u USERNAME)" -F: '{if ($3 == id) print $6 "/Desktop"}' /etc/passwd
```

or

```
awk -v "name=USERNAME" -F: '{if ($1 == name) print $6 "/Desktop"}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: What if the users Desktop's name isn't "Desktop"?

Answer (score 1):

The `xdg-user-dir` utility can help you:

```
$ xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
/home/user/Desktop
```

It only works like this if you're logged as the user though. You can fool it by specifying `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`:

```
$ XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/user xdg-user-dir DESKTOP
/home/user/Desktop
```

If you look at the script itself, it roughly does the same thing as the snippet in Mikel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

the path is `$HOME/Desktop`

test by `echo hello > $HOME/Desktop/testing.txt`

Answer (score -1):

You're making it way more complex than it has to be. `~UserName` is an alias for UserName's home directory.

Use `~UserName/Desktop`.

Comment: They specifically asked for a general and correct way, which also handles the case where the directory is not called "Desktop".